# Issue running below code in unix machine but same code works fine in running windows

Tags: python

I am trying to  replace unicode characters with ascii characters with the below code. Same code is working in windows machine but while running in unix machine I am getting error :

> "TypeError: expected a character buffer object"

```
#!/usr/bin/python2
# coding=utf-8
import sys

s = open(sys.argv[1], "r")

table = {
          0xe4: u'a',
          ord(u'ö'): u'o',
          ord(u'ü'): u'u',
          ord(u'é'): u'e',
          ord(u'ß'): u'b',
        }

for i in s:
    print ("Translated Content in file:",str(i).translate(table));
s.close()
```

Input file (`utf8.txt`) passed to the script with below content

```
sömé täßt
sömé täßt
sömé täßt
```

Expected result is :

```
Translated Content in file: some tabt

Translated Content in file: some tabt

Translated Content in file: some tabt
```

Actual Result in Unix Machine:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "unicode.py", line 17, in <module>
    print ("Translated Content in file:",str(i).translate(table));
TypeError: expected a character buffer object
```

Require suggestions on this issue.

Comment: The difference is not Unix vs Windows; the difference is you are using Python 2 on one machine and Python 3 on the other.

Comment: Unrelated but `ß == ss` in German. Assuming it is what you want to convert to `ASCII`. So `täßt == tasst`

Comment: @DanielRoseman  Yes correct in my windows python 3 is running but in unix i have python 2 running by my organization . How can this script be corrected to work in unix machine running on python 2

Answer (score 0):

You could skip using `translate` and instead, access the table (as a dictionary) directly:

```
for i in s:
    print ("Translated Content in file:",table.get(str(i),str(i)));
```

Answer (score 0):

I see, the problem is that you need to divide the treatment to characters, while now you are applying to strings directly. Can you take a look at this code:

```
for i in s: 
    translated = u'' 
    for c in i.decode('utf8'): 
        translated = translated+table.get(ord(c),c) 
    print ("Translated Content in file:",translated);
```

Comment: I am getting this error when i replace the code File                            
                                                                                                                                  
 File "unicode.py", line 17, in <module>
    for c in i.decode('utf8'):
 "/usr/lib64/python2.7/encodings/utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xf6 in position 1: invalid start byte

Comment: I have tested this code in an online python 2.7 editor (https://repl.it/languages/python) and it works fine. Could you please test it in this online editor? maybe there is some error in your python installation or setup